How to dreate a dynamic ui based on a work flow definition
I want to build a UI dynamically based on a work flow.
For example:
Flow 1 has 3 stages and so the UI will have 3 widgets to capture the respective details. There would also be dependent stages so that a particular stage can't be accessed until the previous stage is done with.
But another user could define the process in 4 steps.
Required features:
Definition of stages in the workflow, dependencies, and list of information to be captured in every stage. This should be accomplished using a GUI based flow builder that uses Jason in the background.
Once this flow is defined, the corresponding UI should be created based on the flow along with back-end dB and action buttons.
I know this sounds like a CMS to a large extent. But I couldn't find definition of workflows in any CMS. Also it lacks flexibility of dB.
Kindly suggest how to go about build this?
